# Visual Studio Automation task generate UI from C# Class definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, automation

How would I build an automation task that would generate ASCX UI controls from a C# class definition?

For example, if I had a class :

```cs
public class Human
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._Name.Trim(); }
        set { this._Name = value; }
    }
    private string _Name = "";


    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return this._DateOfBirth; }
        set { this._DateOfBirth = value; }
    }
    private DateTime _DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1901, 1, 1);

    public int Height
    {
        get { return this._Height; }
        set { this._Height = value; }
    }
    private int _Height = -1;

}
```

I'd like to take the class and generate some Markup that looks like this :

```html
<p>
    <label for="tbName">Name</label>
    <asp:textbox id="tbName" runat=server" ClientIdMode="static"/>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="tbDateOfBirth">DateOfBirth</label>
    <asp:textbox id="tbDateOfBirth" runat=server" ClientIdMode="static" class="date"/>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="tbHeight">Height</label>
    <asp:textbox id="tbHeight" runat=server" ClientIdMode="static" class="int"/>
</p>
```

I'd also like to generate the C# code-behind but I'm sure that's easy enough todo once I've learnt how to reflect the class `Human` and generate this markup.

Any suggestions would be great.   The nearest I've got so far is to use a console application as an External tool, pass the file name and then using a `StreamReader` to read the raw .cs Class definition and generate the .ascx & .ascx.cs files in the correct locations.  Of cause this approach isn't using reflection and I have to manually add the files to the project.

My preferred option would be to somehow focus the class definition and, via a key binding, initialise the automation task to generate and include the new ASCX User Control in the project.  Maybe even ask where in the project the ASCX control should be place.

Thanks for your time :)

**Update** Just to say I'd mentioned the code-behind in passing but really this is where I'd like to generate much more C# to wire-up the textbox's with the respective properties and attach to Insert & Update handlers exposed in the DataServer for the class.

Comment: I'd imagine it would be doable with [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) and reflection.

Comment: I totally agree... and would encourage you to try http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Brilliant, thanks I'll have read through the documents.